# How to solve Jmeter server start error on MacBook: "No such file or directory"?

Tags: macos, jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I am trying to run Jmeter for a distributed load test. I have multiple PC and Macs to be used as slaves. I configured all other slaved properly, but on one particular Mac I get the following:

```
/Library/apache-jmeter-3.3\ 2/bin/jmeter-server ; exit;
C02L14PYF6T6-MacBook-Air:~ user$ /Library/apache-jmeter-3.3\ 2/bin/jmeter-server ; exit;
usage: dirname path
/Library/apache-jmeter-3.3 2/bin/jmeter-server: line 32: /jmeter: No such file or directory
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

I have looked on many other resources, but could not find a solution. I even uninstalled Jmeter using Brew and copied the Jmeter binary and directly put it on desktop, but still getting this error.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

According to source code of `jmeter-server`, line 32 is :

```
${DIRNAME}/jmeter ${RMI_HOST_DEF} -Dserver_port=${SERVER_PORT:-1099} -s -j jmeter-server.log "$@"
```

The error you got tells that `DIRNAME` is empty. This variable is set line 23 :

```
DIRNAME=`dirname $0`
```

I'm not on a mac, but maybe `dirname` does not exists on you system. Or shell on your system misinterpret back quote.

Plus, I see your path contains space. This is definitely not recommended when one want to use command line and scripts.

You may also edit this `jmeter-server` to hardcode some parts.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `jmeter-server ;` the `;` character is the first argument to JMeter program. first argument is directory name in order to change directory for finding JMeter execution folder.

You don't want to change directory so just execute `jmeter-server` without extra characters/arguments

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the issue. I am trying to run V3.3 on a mac.. but for some reason apachejmeter.jar is missing in the version as well as 3.3.2 version. I have downgraded to 3.2.3 version and this has the file in bin folder. Its working fine now.